# Por que não consigo mudar o texto da div com ação submit de botão de form?

Tags: javascript, html

Tentei isso:

```js
let form = document.querySelector('.form');


function postar(evento){
    evento.preventDefault();
    let conteudo = form.querySelector('.escreverTweet').innerText;
    let display = document.querySelector('.display').innerText;
    display += conteudo;

}

form.addEventListener('submit', postar);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quando você fez

```
let display = document.querySelector('.display').innerText;
```

você pegou o conteúdo em innerText do elemento, e nao o elemento, portanto, você nunca alterou o elemento.

podia tentar algo como

```
let display = document.querySelector('.display');
display.innerText += conteudo;
```

Comment: muito obrigado!